# Avalonia .xaml can't go to definition, F12 also don't work, why?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, avalonia

```
<editor:DrawingNode.ContextFlyout>
  <MenuFlyout>
    <MenuItem Header="Cu_t" Command="{Binding CutCommand}" InputGesture="Ctrl+X" />
    <MenuItem Header="_Copy" Command="{Binding CopyCommand}" InputGesture="Ctrl+C" />
    <MenuItem Header="_Paste" Command="{Binding PasteCommand}" InputGesture="Ctrl+V" />
    <MenuItem Header="_Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}" InputGesture="Delete" />
    <MenuItem Header="-" />
    <MenuItem Header="Select _All" Command="{Binding SelectAllCommand, FallbackValue={x:Null}}" InputGesture="Ctrl+A" />
    <MenuItem Header="De_select All" Command="{Binding DeselectAllCommand, FallbackValue={x:Null}}" InputGesture="Escape" />
  </MenuFlyout>
</editor:DrawingNode.ContextFlyout>
```

I want to go to the definition of cut command, but pressing F12 did not go to the definition/source of avalonia. Does avalonia support navigation to the definition of their elements in xaml?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Writing things such as "Except a solution or cause" sounds very demanding! People here help for free, so treating their time with respect is something expected when asking questions. If someone can help, they'll help. I hope someone can - all I can add to your question is that avalonia is a open source project driven by passionate people in their free time, that might not have the tooling to do that because no one did it yet. If you want, you can help improving it by developing tooling!